# Passing request.POST vs the request itself to a django form when uploading multiple files

Tags: python, django, forms, post, request

I am using following form to upload multiple images.

```
class AlbumForm(forms.Form):
album_name = forms.CharField(label='Titel', max_length=100, required=True)
album_description = forms.CharField(label='Beschrijving', widget=forms.Textarea)
images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

In the receiving view i noticed that when i pass request.POST to the form I cannot access the images in the form. On the other hand when i pass the request itself to the form i can access the files but cannot use the form.isValid() method.

Only the multiple image file is not available, the two other values are available as usual.

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    images_form = AlbumForm(request)
    ...
    if images_form.is_valid():
        images = images_form.data.FILES.getlist('images')
        Imgur().create_album(title=images_form.album_name, description=images_form.album_description, images=images)
    ...
```

Following is the html code for the form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{images_form|crispy}}
    <input class="" type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

What is the reason for this difference or what am i doing wrong?

*Edit : the name and description are not available when only using the request, so i guess the correct way to go is to use request.POST, but what is then the correct way to acces the files*

Comment: You need to pass both POST and FILES, as shown in the documente.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I should have seen that in the docs, do you maybe know why the files are not available as a list directly from the form? It does not make a real difference but iam just curious on why you have access them through the request instead of the form itself